# Data Factory configure trigger from a configuration table in sql

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is it possible to configure the execution frequency of a pipeline in data factory?

The idea is to have a parameterization table in SQL server that contains the execution frequency, for example, every 5 minutes, every hour, etc. and with this configuration to be able to launch the execution of a pipeline??

Any idea?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you won’t be able to access or pass `frequency/interval` values of **recurrence** properties of Azure data factory trigger dynamically.

You can share your feedback in [data factory feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c) where it is closely monitored by the product team.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this is going to help accept that the frequenct can alter by chnaging the sql table values compare to checking in the ADF code after updating the trigger .

i think you can use a lookup and read the SQL table and use a IF actvity before actual pipeline logic . The Pipeline should be triggered every 15 mins ( thats the min value , i think ) and the IF activity will decide if it needs to execute the actual logic . I already called out the adavantage , but the downside is

1. Each trigger run will atleast incure the cost of IF activity .
2. I find this to be messy to manage in the long run .